# How to (efficiently) search nuccore to retrieve only annotated sequences?

Tags: database, python, sequence-annotation, public-databases, phylogenetics

I wish to efficiently search [nuccore](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore) to retrieve only annotated sequences.

By "annotated" I mean that the nuccore entry contains annotation information.
An equivalent definition (if I understand correctly) is that the entry's `Feature Table` isn't empty.
 The table can be downloaded by clicking `Send to` in the web page of the nuccore entry.
[image: download_feature_table]
Alternatively, the table can be downloaded using Biopython: `Entrez.efetch(db='nuccore', id=nuccore_id, rettype='ft')`

This definition suggests one answer to my question: Search nuccore normally, then for each entry download its `Feature Table`, and discard each nuccore entry whose table is empty.
The problem is that this would be very inefficient.

My best idea thus far is to add `gene[Feature key]` to my search term.
E.g., instead of `"escherichia coli"[Primary Organism]`, use `("escherichia coli"[Primary Organism]) AND gene[Feature key]`.
This seems to work, but also feels like a quite dirty hack.
Is this a good idea? Or am I missing something crucial here?

Another idea I had was using (Biopython) `Entrez.esummary(db='nuccore', id=nuccore_id)`, and hopefully finding there a `is_sequence_annotated` flag or something similarly wonderful. One of the fields `Entrez.esummary` returns is `Flags`, but I have no idea how to parse it. I asked about it in [another question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/13166/4868).